# How to install the Google drive SDK, google-http-java-client, on eclipse or at least use it in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, google-drive-api

I need a step by step installing list the read me html is of no use

this is what I tried

I downloaded the API beta from here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-http-client-android2

Then I tried transferring the android relevant jar files [from the same link] into a projects libs folder

I then tried this example

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

The first two imports worked but there was some kind of dependency issue.

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;

The second two imports were not supported

import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

Comment: At the time I was experimenting with technologies and chose a different one, so I have no way of knowing if the answer is helpful.Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Google Play Services to the build path.

You can do this by

Opening up SDK browsing to EXTRAS and install Google Play Services
[image: http://i1279.photobucket.com/albums/y522/Vnge/GooglePlayServices_zps2241497e.png]

Then you would want to go to PROJECT -> PROPERTIES -> JAVA BUILD PATH
         Click on ADD EXTERNAL JARS -> Browse to where your android-sdk folder is
         Browse to \extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-service_lib\libs

and then Click on Order and Export
 and then click on Google Play Services Jar

Comment: great solution I looked for this all over. I wish Google had better guide or doumentation